# Golang JSON tags

Tags: go

Suppose I have a struct `Foo`.

```
Foo struct {
        Bar, Baz int
}
```

And I want to marshal this struct into `json` like so:
`{bar : 1, baz : 2}`

How could I achieve that, without splitting my single line multiple name declaration (`Bar, Baz int`) into 2 separate lines using tags.

This works:

> ```
> Foo struct {
>         Bar int `json:"bar"`
>         Baz int `json:"baz"`
> }
> ```

But I'd like:

> ```
> Foo struct {
>         Bar, Baz int `json:???`
> }
> ```

Is the latter even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), No.

```
StructType     = "struct" "{" { FieldDecl ";" } "}" .
FieldDecl      = (IdentifierList Type | AnonymousField) [ Tag ] .
AnonymousField = [ "*" ] TypeName .
Tag            = string_lit .
```

[go](/questions/tagged/go) has a strict syntax favouring the one way to do things.

Comment: To be precise: you are allowed a tag after the list, but it would be the same tag for every field in that declaration, which doesn't help you here. (See the last paragraph of this section of the spec.)

Answer (score -1):

Go has a built in package encoding/json that can help you out in this situation.

Here is the godocs for the library http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

Here is an example I made using the library http://play.golang.org/p/YOhj2qKg-2

edit: As tarrsalla said below me, go prefers the "one way to do things" and it would work out better for you in the long run if you used that "way"

Comment: I know that, but I want to name JSON keys differently.

Comment: I can't really help you there as I have never had to do that myself. Best way I can think of is running a `strings.Replace(jsonString, "Bar:", "bar:", 1)` on the resulting string. I will update my example with that.

Comment: Well I could marshal into map[string]interface{} (I think), but than type safety would be lost.

Comment: I have modified it once again to give the exact output you were asking for. Is there a reason why the replace method won't work for you? Unfortunately I don't know enough about how go handles json to do it any other way.

Comment: Replace could work, but `ToLower` the whole thing would be even easier xD. But I don't want to do either, Ill just do tags in struct to keep it tidy.

Comment: Haha ya. I got a little tunnel visioned. You can always just attach a function to your struct that does all of this for you. ie. `func ConvertToJSON() string`. That is pretty tidy but tags might still be better. All up to you.